# Best move arrow in Scid vs PC

Tags: analysis, scid

Is there a way to display the best move found by the engine on the main board? Lichess has arrows showing the best move (and even for the second, third, etc best lines). Is this possible in Scid vs PC?

Comment: http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Analysis.htm

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Scid vs PC help](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Variations.htm) use menu options:

Options / Moves / Show Variation Arrows